# in Jenkins, how to set higher priority to a particular view over other view?

Tags: jenkins

I have setup multiple views in jenkins. For example View-A, View-B. 
Now I want to give higher priority to projects under View-A over View-B such that when projects from both the views are in queue, projects from View-A gets executed first.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [Priority Sorter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Priority+Sorter+Plugin). With that plugin you will be able to use `Jobs included in a view` option, like this:
[image]